# Angular 2. SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, angular2

При попытке создания новой коллекции в mongoDB, вываливается вот такая вот ошибка:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:416
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:416
error_handler.js:60 SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Response.Body.json (body.js:24)
    at MapSubscriber.project (left-bar.service.ts:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:77)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:363)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:362)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:416)
```

**но всё же коллекция создается!** 

Как я понял Метод **.subscribe()** получает некорректные данные от сервиса.
Данные в каком виде должен принимать Метод **.subscribe()**?

 
--------------------**left-bar.component.ts**--------------------

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LeftBarService } from '../left-bar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-bar',
  templateUrl: './left-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-bar.component.sass']
})
export class LeftBarComponent implements OnInit {
  categories = [];

  constructor(private leftBarService: LeftBarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.leftBarService.getAllCategories().subscribe(category => {
      this.categories = category;
    });
  }

  addCategory(category) {
    let newCategory = {
      name: category
    }
    this.leftBarService.addCategory(newCategory)
      .subscribe( categ => {
        this.categories.push(newCategory);
      });
  }
}
```

---------------------------**left-bar-service.ts**---------------------

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LeftBarService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Get all categories
  getAllCategories() {
    return this.http.get('/categories')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  // Add category
  addCategory(newCategory) { 
    return this.http.post('/categories', newCategory)
      .map( res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: посмотри что именно тебе сервер возвращает

Comment: Вы лучше покажите что в JSON возвращается

Comment: @Grundy Request payload: {"name":"hello"}

Comment: @Денисоед, request - это то, что ты послал. А тебе надо посмотреть, что ты получил

Comment: @Grundy Там Response а ни Request)))) Я ошибся

Comment: @Денисоед, посмотри что ты написал в комментарии :-) Ну и ты почему-то только заголовки ответа показал, обрати внимание на _**Request** Headers:_. А сам ответ - не показал

Comment: @Денисоед, _Там Response а ни Request)))) Я ошибся_ - Нет такого пункта как `response payload`. И для _{"name":"hello"}_ ошибка _Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0_ - никак не могла произойти. Она могла произойти, **только** если ответ сервера начинается с символа `O`, какой-нибудь `ObjectId`

Comment: @Grundy =) Тысяча извинений

Answer (score -1):

Ты высылаешь не валидный JSON, а к примеру строку. Один из вариантов решения проблемы приведет ниже. При этом независимо от того, что вы отправите с сервера в другие компоненты придет ожидаемый результат.

```
 addCategory(newCategory) { 
     return this.http.post('/categories', newCategory)
                 .map(res => {
                   try { return res.json(); } 
                   catch (err) { return res; }
                 })
```

Но лучше всего пересмотреть серверный код и высылать валидный `JSON`. Тогда конструкция `try catch` не понадобится. И можно будет оставить `res.json();`

Comment: json, как это ни странно - обычная строка, если ее не парсить - она строкой и останется.

Comment: Может выразился не так, но ответ должен помочь

Comment: @Lestoroer Спасибо за помощь

Comment: "Сервер, скорее всего, уже присылает JS объект" - это как так?

Comment: Не, единственно в чем может помочь ответ, скрывать ошибки, чтобы они потом в другом месте вылезли

Comment: @Grundy Ответ выше помог

Comment: @Денисоед, ага, ты вместо того, чтобы проверить что именно шлет тебе сервер, просто скрываешь ошибку и неизвестно что получаешь дальше

Comment: @Grundy **dev-tool** > **Network** > **Responce** = Ok!

Comment: @Денисоед, теперь ты видишь свою ошибку??? Строка `"Ok!"` - не json, именно поэтому ты и падаешь. Для решения не надо ставить костыль, надо просто не пытаться получать json там где на самом деле обычный текст

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Денисоед, для получения просто текста используй `.text()`

Comment: @Денисоед. Он в некотором прав. Возможно ты высылаешь с сервера что-то вроде этого `'{some:some}'`. А надо  `{some: 'some'}`. Но еще бывает с сервера отправляешь просто строку, например, `some`, но нужно это строку оборачивать в объект `{some: 'some'}` и из объекта уже получать нужную информацию

Comment: @Lestoroer Как узнать что высылается с сервера?

Comment: @Денисоед `.map(res => {
                   console.log(res);
                   try { return res.json(); } 
                   catch (err) { return res; }
                 })`

Comment: @Lestoroer чуть позже отпишусь)

Comment: @Lestoroer Ответ от сервера: **Response => body:"OK",headers:Headers,ok:true,status:200,statusText:"OK",type:2,url:"http://localhost:3000/categories"**

Comment: @Grundy Всё как вы и говорили)

Comment: Оберни на сервере "OK" в `{status: 'OK'}`. Либо почитай как правильно с сервера отправлять статус.

Comment: @Lestoroer Ok =)!